# Cannot directly count Nulls in SSMS

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, null

I am trying to count the number of nulls in column using COUNT and a WHERE clause. The result of this query returns counts of 0 when there are nulls in the table for Attr_620_Lookup. I could count all rows and subtract IS NOT NULL.. but is there a way to directly count nulls?

```
SELECT Attr_616 AS Location, COUNT(Attr_620_Lookup)
FROM dbo.AttributesDenormalized AS ad
WHERE (Attr_620_Lookup IS NULL)
GROUP BY Attr_616
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify an expression in `COUNT` it will count non-null values.  Just use `COUNT(*)` instead:

```
SELECT Attr_616 AS Location, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.AttributesDenormalized AS ad
WHERE (Attr_620_Lookup IS NULL)
GROUP BY Attr_616
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what @DStanley mentioned you could also use a case statement with SUM:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MyField IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TheSum
FROM TheTable
```

This would be great if you were dealing with NULLS and NON NULLS, however, your WHERE clause specifically asks for NULLs...meaning my case statement is a bit redundant as you've already stated `...WHERE MyField IS NULL`

Comment: or along similar lines:  SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN MyField IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS TheCount FROM TheTable.